# Sed not working with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a `file.php` that is changed externally, with line like:

```
echo "\n<!-- BEGIN APP v" . APP_VERSION . " - http://saite.com/ -->\n";
```

Knowing the pattern it still will follow, I need to suppress this message with just newline.

But I cannot find a way to that. I try to run this code from terminal:

```
PAT="<!-- BEGIN APP [^>]+>"
TO=""
sed -i "s/$PAT/$TO/g" file.php
```

But the file is not changed.

Comment: THe exclamation mark is a history command when interpreted by the shell, so the first `PAT="<!-- BEGIN APP [^>]+>"` should fail with `-bash: !--: event not found` (as it tried on my system to find a previous entered commandstarting with `--` ...

Comment: Confirm, but i don't see that message... my command is inside script. May be this reason ..

Comment: History expansion doesn't occur by default from within a script.

Comment: Dinner is close, sorry - maybe sprinkle some backslashes to safeguard the spaces and the character class squarebrackets in the pattern (and you could remove thtat `$TO` completely ;-) oh and do you have access to the stderr of the script? Did not know, that these are inside script, @TomFenech is right.

Comment: Many `sed` implementations have a very limited regex repertoire. Try with `*` instead of `+` (or add an `-r` option if your `sed` has that).

Comment: @tripleee is referring to the fact that sed by default uses BRE where `+` is literal, using `-r` will enable ERA where `+` is a metacharacter as you expect. Note that to enable ERA on BSD sed one should use `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this with using `*` instead of `+` in regex and additional option `-r`.

```
sed -i -r ...
```

Thanks to @tripleee and @andlrc